# How to search specific strings in a text file and modify them

Tags: string, vb.net, text, import

I've been trying to import a text file, .po format to be exact, which contains regular text.

> [Text Example]
>
> #: C:\Users\andrei\Desktop\sitemile_themes\ProjectTheme/archive-project.php:69
>      #: C:\Users\andrei\Desktop\sitemile_themes\ProjectTheme/taxonomy.php:108
>      msgid "All Posted Projects"
>      msgstr "Все запросы"
>
> #: C:\Users\andrei\Desktop\sitemile_themes\ProjectTheme/archive-project.php:70
>      #: C:\Users\andrei\Desktop\sitemile_themes\ProjectTheme/taxonomy.php:109
>      #, php-format
>      msgid "Latest Posted Projects in %s"
>      msgstr "Последние запросы в %s"

Once imported, i need to go through imported text and find strings which start with msgid "example" and msgstr "example 2" and import those into a listview1, which has 2 columns, as msgid being an item, while msgstr being a subitem, would look like this after imported.

> [Example Listview1]

```
Column One  |  Column Two
Example     |  Example 2
--------------------------
```

And import every string that is in quotation marks under 'msgid' and 'msgstr'
I've had no problem with importing the text into vb.net form, but i seem to not be able to go through imported text and pull out 'msgid "example"' and 'msgstr  "example 2"' strings. Anyone has any idea how to achieve this?

EDIT: I'm sorry, i forgot to show the code i'm currently trying to use!
To import the file, i use this code

```
       Dim fileReader As System.IO.StreamReader
        fileReader =
My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("C:\Users\pasha\Desktop\en_US.po")
        Dim stringReader As String
        stringReader = fileReader.ReadToEnd()
        TextBox1.Text = stringReader
```

Which works alright, but for some reason it puts it in my textbox(multi line enabled) as a whole, ignoring the lines that the original text file has.

And for scanning strings i use

```
 For Each line In TextBox1.Text
    If line.ToString.Contains("msgid") Then
        ListView1.Items.Add(line.ToString.Replace("msgid ", ""))
    End If
Next
```

But for some reason this code doesn't even add a single line that it finds, i don't think it even finds anything at all. Sorry for a newbie coding, i'm new to all of this.

Comment: Hard to help without any code.  If you just want us to write code for you, you came to the wrong place. Read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Well, what have you done that is not working? An example of your efforts is a good way to getting answers

Comment: I'm sorry! I've edited the post and included the code that i'm currently using.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  UI Controls make horrible variables.  `File.ReadAllLines()` is all you need to load the data.  The filtering in the second snippet is just looking for if a line CONTAINS the string, not STARTSWITH as the post insdicates

Answer (score 0):

This will assume you always have "msgid" and "msgstr" at the same time. You can also walk a little slower by checking the first " so that if you have extra spaces it won't affect the result. If it will ALWAYS be like that no matter what then you can use it like that.

```
        Dim fileReader As System.IO.StreamReader
        fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("C:\dump\test.po")
        Dim stringReader As String = ""
        stringReader = fileReader.ReadToEnd()
        Dim msgList As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String))
        Do Until InStr(stringReader.ToLower, "msgid") = 0
            Dim xmsgid As String = ""
            Dim xmsgstr As String = ""
            stringReader = Strings.Mid(stringReader, InStr(stringReader.ToLower, "msgid") + 7)
            xmsgid = Strings.Left(stringReader, InStr(stringReader, Chr(34)) - 1)
            stringReader = Strings.Mid(stringReader, InStr(stringReader.ToLower, "msgstr") + 8)
            xmsgstr = Strings.Left(stringReader, InStr(stringReader, Chr(34)) - 1)
            msgList.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(xmsgid, xmsgstr))
        Loop
```

Slower walk in the string but at least you see the concept.

```
        Dim fileReader As System.IO.StreamReader
        fileReader =
        My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("C:\dump\test.po")
        Dim stringReader As String = ""
        stringReader = fileReader.ReadToEnd()
        Dim msgList As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String))
        Do Until InStr(stringReader.ToLower, "msgid") = 0
            Dim xmsgid As String = ""
            Dim xmsgstr As String = ""
            stringReader = Strings.Mid(stringReader, InStr(stringReader.ToLower, "msgid"))
            stringReader = Strings.Mid(stringReader, InStr(stringReader.ToLower, Chr(34)) + 1)
            xmsgid = Strings.Left(stringReader, InStr(stringReader, Chr(34)) - 1)
            stringReader = Strings.Mid(stringReader, InStr(stringReader.ToLower, "msgstr"))
            stringReader = Strings.Mid(stringReader, InStr(stringReader.ToLower, Chr(34)) + 1)
            xmsgstr = Strings.Left(stringReader, InStr(stringReader, Chr(34)) - 1)
            msgList.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(xmsgid, xmsgstr))
        Loop
```